# Do you know something similar to XmlDiffPatch for text files?

Tags: .net, diff, patch

I recently discovered a .NET [XmlDiffPatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx) library written by Microsoft. It allows calculate differences of two XML files. It finds even moved code inside the file.

Do you know something similar for text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google diff-match-patch might be what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/